# How to convert a string to a complex number?

Tags: go, complex-numbers

How to change string a type value to complex number?

I need to perform arithmetic operations on complex numbers which are passed through command line arguments.

For example:

```
go run file.go 3-4i + 7+2i
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Go 1.15, there is a `ParseComplex` function in the `strconv` package:

https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseComplex

Comment: I tried to use ParseComplex fuction but its throwing error. Installed go version-1.16.3.Is there any different approach to accept complex numbers through command line arguments to perform arithmetic operations. Please help

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mre] of the problem you have encountered.